# How can I create a pause label in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, pause

I want to create a "PAUSED" sign that appears when the game is paused. It should have a white background and the text "PAUSED".

```
--------
|PAUSED|
--------
```

The docs says that you can't subclass a node to do custom drawing, which is sad :(

So I decided to use a sprite node with white color and a label node to do this. I can then add the label node as a child of the sprite node:

```
let pauseText = SKLabelNode(text: "PAUSED")
pauseText.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()
pauseText.fontName = "Times New Roman"
pauseText.fontSize = 30
pauseNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size: pauseText.frame.size)
pauseNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
pauseText.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(pauseNode.frame), CGRectGetMidY(pauseNode.frame))
pauseNode.zPosition = 999
pauseNode.addChild(pauseText)
```

where `pauseNode` is the sprite node and `pauseText` is the label node.

But this doesn't seem to work. The sprite node shows up as a thin rectangle and I can't see any text in it.

How to do this?

Comment: The font name isn't valid. You need to uses one of the font names as shown on http://iosfonts.com

Comment: No, I tried to only put a label node (with the same font family) on the screen and it works. But I really want the background to be white. @CleverError

Comment: @Sweeper You might consider loading specific font, rather than entire font family . Read more [here](https://gilesey.wordpress.com/2015/01/14/ios-spritekit-font-loading-times-of-sklabelnodes/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you're assigning to `pauseText.position` will cause the text be drawn off the screen.

From the [SKNode docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html):

> Every node in a node tree provides a coordinate system to its children. After a child is added to the node tree, it is positioned inside its parent’s coordinate system by setting its position properties.

If you set the position to (0, 0) you'll see the text but it is up a bit too high. Then just change the y value so it is vertically centered in its parent.

```
pauseText.position = CGPointMake(0, -pauseNode.frame.height / 2)
```

Which will show

[image]

---

On a side node, I learned that `fontName` can be either a font name or a font family name so thats cool.

Comment: But isn't my code setting the position of the pause text already? `pauseText.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(pauseNode.frame), CGRectGetMidY(pauseNode.frame)): `

Comment: You code is setting the position but it is not the right position for what you want.

Comment: @CleverError Note that loading entire font family instead of specific font can impact on loading time and you might experience noticeable lag that way. Loading specific font is the most performant solution in many cases.